# Merge [range-voting] and [score-voting]

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

I don't have the privileges to even suggest this synonym, apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are five questions affected:

<s>[What voting majority is needed to present and pass cryptocurrency smartcards for social security in a ballot vote?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/15186/what-voting-majority-is-needed-to-present-and-pass-cryptocurrency-smartcards-for) (doesn't seem related -score only)</s> removed tag

[How does Score-Runoff (STAR voting) compare with plain Score voting?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/14221/how-does-score-runoff-star-voting-compare-with-plain-score-voting) <s>(includes both tags)</s> removed score-voting

[How do abstentions affect Majority Judgment voting?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/28321/how-do-abstentions-affect-majority-judgment-voting) (range only)

[How does range voting deal with lack of objective scoring?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/652/how-does-range-voting-deal-with-lack-of-objective-scoring) (range only)

[Has range voting been successfully implemented anywhere?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/49/has-range-voting-been-successfully-implemented-anywhere) (range only)

[score-voting]

> Score voting (also called range, evaluative, or utilitarian voting) is a voting method in which voters give independent numerical ratings to each candidate.
>
> The scores are then averaged (if abstentions are allowed) or summed (if not), and the winner is the candidate with the highest total score.

[range-voting]

> Range voting (also called ratings summation, average voting, cardinal ratings, score voting, 0–99 voting, the score system, or the point system) is a voting method for one-seat elections under which voters score each candidate, the scores are added up, and the candidate with the highest score wins.

And they link to the same wikipedia article ([range voting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_voting))

<s>I think this is a reasonable merge.</s>

It appears score-voting is extraneous. It is on two questions, one also has range-voting, and the other shouldn't have it.

---

And now I edited both question to not have it. score-voting is no longer used anywhere.

Comment: Yes, they're literally 2 different names for the same thing.  See http://rangevoting.org/ and http://scorevoting.net/, for instance.

Comment: But they should still be synonyms for when people try to enter score voting as a tag for their question